# Subsetting nominal variables in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set similar to this one:

```
x <- sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05))
y <- sample(1:40, 1000, replace=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(x,y)

str(d)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  2 variables:
$ x: Factor w/4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 4 3 ...
$ y: int  28 35 14 4 34 36 30 35 26 9 ...

table(d$x)
A   B   C   D 
115 204 637 44
```

So in my real data set i have multiple thousands of these category (A, B, C, D).

The `str()` of my real dataset

```
str(realdata)
data.frame':    346340 obs. of  91 variables:
$ author       : Factor w/ 42590 levels "-jon-","--LZR--",..: 1962 3434 1241 7666 6235 2391 1196 2779 1881 339 ...
$ created_utc  : Factor w/ 343708 levels "2015-05-01 02:00:41",..: 14815 23163 2281 3569 5922 7211 15783 5512 13485 8591 ...
$ group    : Factor w/ 5 levels "xyz","abc","bnm",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
....
```

Now i want to subset the data, so i have only the rows of those $authors (or `$x` in the `d` dataframe) in my new dataframe that have more than 100 entries in total.

I tried the following:

```
dnew <- subset(realdata, table(realdata$author) > 100)
```

It gives me a result, but it seems the not all entries of the authors were included. Although it should be way more, i just get 1.3% of the rows of the complete dataset. I checked it manually (with excel) and it should be way more than that (approx. 30%). The manual analysis showed that 1.2 % of $author stand for 30% of the entries. So it seems he just gave me one row with the $author who has more than 100 entries, but not all of his entries.

Do you know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I. Data frame `d` with four levels

```
  table(d$x)

  #  A   B   C   D 
  # 92 232 630  46
```

II. Checking which level has greater than 100 records

```
  which(table(d$x)>100)
  # B C 
  # 2 3
```

III. Subsetting `d` data frame having only records belonging to levels which have greater than 100 records ie. `level B` and `level C`

```
  result <- d[ d$x %in%  names(table(d$x))[table(d$x) > 100] , ]
  dim(result)
  # [1] 862   2

  str(result)
  # 'data.frame':   862 obs. of  2 variables:
  #  $ x: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 ...
  #  $ y: int  29 32 27 40 30 38 8 16 2 23 ...
```

Level `A` and `D` still persists with `0 records`

```
  table(result$x)

  #   A   B   C   D 
  #   0 232 630   0
```

IV. Removing the levels with 0 records using `factor()`

```
  result$x <- factor(result$x)

  str(result)
  # 'data.frame':   860 obs. of  2 variables:
  #  $ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "B","C": 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 ...
  #  $ y: int  29 32 27 40 30 38 8 16 2 23 ...

  table(result$x)
  #   B   C 
  # 232 630
```

Comment: @akrun I have no clue you have added that, for my answer I used combination of two links, I tried it and then posted, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835233/subset-based-on-frequency-level
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195826/drop-factor-levels-in-a-subsetted-data-frame
Your answer for base R also works I checked that too, the levels were still persisting in data, so I dropped them following the second link. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We can do this easily with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d)`, grouped by 'x', `if` the number of observations is greater than 100, we Subset the Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
ddt <- setDT(d)[, if(.N > 100) .SD, x]
```

---

Or if we are using `dplyr`, the same approach can be used.

```
library(dplyr)
dpl <- d %>%
        group_by(x) %>%
        filter(n() > 100) %>%
        droplevels()
str(dpl)
#Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 866 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "B","C": 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
# $ y: int  25 25 13 11 2 32 12 15 12 3 ...
```

---

Also, in using the `base R`, the `table` can be helpful

```
v1 <- table(d$x)
d1 <- subset(d, x %in% names(v1)[v1 > 100])
```

As the column 'x' is `factor`, when we `subset` the dataset, the levels persist, to remove that use `droplevels`

```
d2 <- droplevels(d1)
```

As the OP didn't set the `seed`, the output will be different for each person.

```
str(d2)
#'data.frame':   866 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "B","C": 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
#$ y: int  25 25 13 11 2 32 12 15 12 3 ...
```

Comment: I tried the version with dplyr. It works with the test dataframe. Alas I get the error message, when applying it to my real data set: Error: invalid subscript type 'integer'. I checked, the $author is a factor, as is x. I used the following command auth <- realdata %>%  group_by(realdata$author) %>%  filter(n() > 100)

Comment: @8bytez You are not even using the syntax in my code `group_by(realdata$author)` is not used by me.

Comment: hey @akrun. sorry, i tried the rest of your code after trying the other version. It probably works as well. Thank you for helping me! As i said, your code worked perfectly fine with the test sample. Alas, when i changed the variable numbers to that of my real data set, it gave me this error message. Thats why the syntax code which is not from you. It is my real data variables.

Comment: @8bytez No problem.  I guess it has to do with the version of `dplyr` I am using 0.5.0