# Subset a table column from a dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe

One of the columns (`new`) in the dataframe below is a table.

```r
#dput(head(df1))
structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7), b = c(2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 
7), c = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7), new = list(structure(2:1, .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("1", "2")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), structure(1:2, .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("2", "3")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), structure(1:2, .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("2", "3")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), structure(2:1, .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("4", "5")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), structure(c(`5` = 3L), .Dim = 1L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    "5"), .Names = ""), class = "table"), structure(c(`7` = 3L), .Dim = 1L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    "7"), .Names = ""), class = "table"))), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The `new` column is a result of `apply(df1, 1, table)`.
An example of the `new` column subsetting using  `df1[4, "new"][[1]]` 
produces the following output.

```r
df1[4, "new"][[1]]

#4 5 --> Vals
#2 1 --> Freq
```

I want to formulate a condition such as give me all the `Vals` where `Freq` in the `new` column is greater than or equal to some condition and use it to subset the `new` column.

Here is an example and what I have done so far.

```r
df1[4, "new"][[1]][]>=2
#    4     5 
# TRUE FALSE 

# Subsetting using the above logical
as.integer(names(df1[4, "new"][[1]][df1[4, "new"][[1]][]>=2]))
#[1] 4
```

The result is what I expect. However, it is verbose, and I will be happy if there is a shorter version of it (that is not a pressing issue at the moment though I'll be grateful as well as happy to learn writing clear and concise lines).

The pressing problem I have is how to modify the condition `as.integer(names(df1[4, "new"][[1]][df1[4, "new"][[1]][]>=2]))` and apply it to the whole column. For example, for a condition column new `== 3`, `5` and `7` are the expected outputs.

I've seen similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835233/subset-based-on-frequency-level) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204257/subset-data-frame-based-on-number-of-rows-per-group) but didn't help figure out how to apply the subset condition to a column which is a table.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want to return? If the condition is >3, you want the last two rows to be returned? Or a vector containing just 5 and 7? What if the condition is >=2? Would you return all the rows?

Comment: Thank you. The output I want is just `5` and `7`; and when condition is `>=2`, will be specific values (`names`) from the `new` column satisfying the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Investigating the `class` of the object (i.e. the column) yields `"list"`.

```
class(df1$new)
# [1] "list"
```

Usually we use e.g. the `lapply()` function to apply a function to elements of a list. To rather obtain vectors or matrices than lists as a result we could try `sapply`.

So, define your condition,

```
COND <- 2
```

and use your function in a `sapply`:

```
sapply(df1$new, function(x) as.numeric(names(x[x >= COND])))
# [1] 1 3 3 4 5 7
```

Comment: Thanks and just pointing I've to `unlist` the `sapply` to get an output similar to yours and which is exactly what I want. Thank you.